# If $a_n = a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$ where $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 1$, what is the recurrence relation for $a_{2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm interested about the sequence [A002249](https://oeis.org/A002249) in the OEIS and I have a question about this sequence :

Is it possible to find a reccurence relation for $a_{2^n}$ with only $a_{2^n} = ba_{n-1}^p - ca_{n-2}^q - ... - da_{n-m}^r$ ?

Here is what I observed :

I found than you can write $a_{2^n} = a_{n-1}^2 - 2^{2^{(n-1)}+1}$ and you can write $2^{2^{(n+1)}+1} = \frac{b_n^2}{2}$ with $b_{0} = 4$ for $n > 2$ but I don't know how to get a formula with only $a_{n}$.

Can anyone help me please ?

EDIT : you can write the sequence as $4^{2^n} \cdot ((\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{8} (3 i \sqrt7))^{(2^n)} + (\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} (3 i \sqrt7))^{(2^n)})$

Not sure if it helps.

Comment: One can solve for $a_n$ in closed form, that might help.  Frankly, though, the subsequence you are interested in doesn't look very promising:  $\{1,-1,1,-31,449, 70529,-3615594751,\cdots\}$

Comment: @lulu, I noticed something interesting with this sequence about the divisibilty of some numbers, this is why I'm interested by a recurrence relation.

Comment: Sure, but, as I mentioned, any recurrence is going to have to look pretty gruesome.  My guess is you'll want to try a different route.

Comment: When you add $+3$ it seems it divides $W_p = \frac{2^p+1}{3}$ only if $W_p$ is prime and $p>3$, for example $70529+3$ is divided by by $W_5$, $-23820962743960351231+3$ is divided by $W_7$ etc.

Comment: Pretend that $a_n=n$ for all $n$. Is a recurrence such as what you want possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> dl;dr: The proposed relation cannot exist.

Some useful pointers and additional information:
The sequence is known as [Lucas Sequence of the 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence)

$$a_n = V_n = V_n(P,Q)$$
with parameters $P=1$, $Q=2$. It is filed as [OEIS A002249](https://oeis.org/A002249). $V_n$ satisfies many (recurrence) relations and cross-relations to other Lucas sequences.  One of them is

$$V_{2n} = V_n^2-2Q^n = V_n^2 - 2^{n+1}$$
which
you can use to compute $V_{2^n}$ in $n$ steps starting at $V_1=1$, which might be useful. Let $a$ and $b$ denote the two distinct eigenvalues of the associated linear recurrence, i.e.

$$a,b = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{-7}}2$$

Notice that $ab=Q=2$, $a+b=P=1$ and $|a|=|b|=\sqrt2$. Then we have

$$V_n = a^n+b^n = a^n(1+b^n/a^n) = a^n(1+\varepsilon^n)$$
with $\varepsilon=(\sqrt{-7}-3)/4$ and $|\varepsilon|=|a/b| = 1$.
Hence $V_n$ grows like $|a|^n$, see for example the [logarithmic scatter plots on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002249/graph).

Now suppose that a recurrenc relation as proposed exists, i.e. there are $m$ constants $\lambda_k$ and $e_k$ such that

$$a_{2^n} = \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k a_{n-k}^{e_k}\tag1$$

Then the right-hand side grows like $\mathit{const}\cdot|a|^{e(n-k)}$ where $e=\max\{e_k\}$, but the left-hand side grows like $|a|^{2^n}$.  As $|a|>1$, **these two growth rates cannot be reconciled, and thus a relation like $(1)$ cannot exist.**

Comment: @kijinSeija: For a rigoros investigation of the growth rate see [Growth rate of $|a^n+b^n|$ where $a,b=(1\pm\sqrt{-7})/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4531272/746312)