# Growth rate of $|a^n+b^n|$ where $a,b=(1\pm\sqrt{-7})/2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, diophantine-approximation

For the real sequence

$$V_n = |a^n+b^n| \quad\text{ with }\quad a=\frac12(1+\sqrt{-7}),\ \  b=\frac12(1-\sqrt{-7}) \tag1$$

I'd like to derive some estimates on the growth rate of $V_n$ and $V_{2^n}$.

It's clear that
$$|V_n| = |a^n+b^n| = |a|^n|1+(b/a)^n)| \leqslant 2^{1+n/2}\tag2$$
because $|a|=|b|=\sqrt2$. What's missing is a estimate from below like:

$$|V_{2^n}| > C\cdot 2^{n/2}\quad\text{for infinitely many }n \text{ and any }C.\tag 3$$

$V_n=V_n(P=1,Q=2)$ is [OEIS A002249](https://oeis.org/A002249) which is a [Lucas Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) of the 2nd Kind with eigenvalues $a$ and $b$ which satisfy $ab=Q$ and $a+b=P$.  $V_n$ satisfies many (recurrence) relations, for example

$$V_{2n} = V_n^2-2^{n+1}\tag4$$

which might be useful to estimate $V_{2^n}$.  Where I am stuck is the relation

$$V_n=a^n(1+\varepsilon^n)\quad\text{ where }\quad \varepsilon=\frac{\sqrt{-7}-3}4~\text{ and }~|\varepsilon| = 1\tag 5$$

so that I don't see how to bound $1+\varepsilon^n$ from below like $|1+\varepsilon^{2^n}|>\mathit{const}>0$ (or similar) infinitely many times. It seems to be related to diophantine approximations of $\varepsilon$, but I don't see how to proceed.

Purpose of the estimate is a conclusion in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4529985/746312) where I used the growth rate to show that a specific representation of $V_{2^n}$ does not exist. I thought it was obvious, but the more I think about it, the less obvious it becomes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Euler's formula, $a = \sqrt{2} e^{i\theta}$ and $b = \sqrt{2} e^{-i\theta}$ where $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{7})$.

$$ a^n + b^n = 2^{n/2} e^{in \theta} + 2^{n/2} e^{-in \theta} = 2^{1+n/2} \cos(n\theta)$$

$$ V_n = 2^{1+n/2} \left|\cos(n\theta)\right| $$

If $\left|\cos(n\theta)\right| < \frac{1}{2}$ then
$$\cos(2n\theta) = 2\cos^2 (n\theta) - 1 < -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\left|\cos(2n\theta)\right| > \frac{1}{2} $$

So for at least one of $n=2^k$ or $n=2^{k+1}$, and therefore for infinitely many $n=2^k$,

$$ V_n \geq 2^{n/2} $$

(This is also another way to show $V_n \leq 2^{1+n/2}$ for all $n$.)

Comment: Euler's formula is one's first thought, yes...

Comment: Some formula are not correct, maybe they sould read $|V_n|$ instead of $V_n$?.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts $V_n$ is always a positive real, right?

Comment: @aschepler: No, infinitely many elements are negative.  The sequence goes like: 2, 1, −3, −5, 1, 11, 9, −13, −31, −5, 57, 67, −47, −181, -87, 275, 449, −101, −999, −797, 1201, 2795, 393, −5197, −5983, 4411, 16377, 7555, −25199, −40309, 10089, 90707, 70529, −110885, −251943, −30173, 473713, 534059, −413367, −1481485, ... It's $$V_n = V_{n-1}-2V_{n-2}$$

Comment: That sequence is $a^n+b^n$. You defined $V_n = |a^n+b^n|$.